# Creating a parent and child table, does child need its own primary id column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

When we create parent-child tables, does the child table need its own primary key, or should the foreign key of the parent be used as the primary key?

Example:

I have a table that stores users, which is defined like:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    'id' bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'username' varchar(32),
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'))
```

I want to make a second table that stores some more information about a user, like their favorite animals. Should that table have its own 'id' column as well as a separate foreign key for the linked user?:

```
CREATE TABLE users_extra_info (
    'id' bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'fk_user_id' bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    'fav_mammal' varchar(32),
    'fav_reptile' varchar(32),
     ...
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
    KEY 'fk_user_id' ('fk_user_id'))
```

or do you usually just drop the 'id' column since the foreign key has to be unique?:

```
CREATE TABLE users_extra_info (
    'fk_user_id' bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    'fav_mammal' varchar(32),
    'fav_reptile' varchar(32),
     ...
    PRIMARY KEY ('fk_user_id'))
```

Thanks

Comment: Every table should have its own id.  It takes up very little space and makes your tables much easier to deal with.  If the relationship is one to one between users and their favorite animal, it could easily just stay in the same table.

Comment: Foreign Key Need not to be unique. Its based on your requirement. Think what if you want to store info abt employee from different departments. dapartment_id is going to be FK for emp table but dapartment_id need not to be unique in emp table.

Comment: @paqogomez yes the relationship is 1 to 1, I was just thinking what happens if I have 30 "favorite" columns? Should I put them all directly in the users table? Or should I split them up like this in the first place?

Comment: @user1219278 I think it's a good idea to keep the tables separate especially if your `users` table contains login credentials or other sensitive information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a matter of principle, not related to other tables, each table should have a `PRIMARY KEY` in order for you to be able to distinguish one row from another.  While it's not always necessary to absolutely identify individual rows that is often a requirement.

In the event of a true one-to-one relationship (or a one-to-zero-or-one relationship, which also occurs), because the foreign key is necessarily unique it can also be used as the primary key of the subsidiary table.  There is absolutely no reason at all to introduce a *second* unique column in that case.

However, one-to-one and one-to-zero-or-one relationships are less common than one-to-many relationships.  In that more common case, you cannot use only the foreign key columns as the primary key since they are not unique in the child table.  In this case you can choose either to introduce an additional integer key or created a *composite* primary key using the foreign key column(s) and one or more other columns that, together, are guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the normalization rules.

Here's the link http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the additional columns to another table, I don't see a reason to have an extra id column. Below is what I would do. Another benefit from this approach is that you ensure 1 to 1 relationship. If you had a separate ID column, you would be able to have many rows in users_extra_info linked to one row in users.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id int,
    username varchar(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE users_extra_info (
    fk_user_id int,
    fav_mammal varchar(32),
    fav_reptile varchar(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (fk_user_id),
    foreign key (fk_user_id) references users(id));
```

You can also think about cascading deletion.